# Ubuntu Studio 14.10: Need Driver for Epson Workforce 1100

Tags: 14.10, ubuntu-studio

I am running Ubuntu Studio 14.10. I am trying to Find and Install a driver for my Epson Workforce 1100 printer connected over USB.

Comment: Did you check the actual epson site?

Comment: Yes, I could not obtain a driver.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

After it completes, open Printers from the dash and add the printer. The driver will be available here:

[image]

Comment: Entering the terminal command returns `printer-driver-gutenprint is already the newest version`. Because I am using Ubuntu Studio, I access printers through `Settings Manager`. Clicking on `Hardware->Printers->Add` Gives me a choice between `Serial Port #1 | Serial Port #2 | Enter URI | >Network Printer`

Comment: If you open a terminal and do: tail -f /var/log/syslog and unplug and replug the printer, is it detected? Get out of _tail_ with Ctrl+c.

Comment: And, of course, with the printer turned on after it's plugged back in.

Comment: I got it working. The OS was struggling to identify the printer on the rear bank of USB ports. It still took a while when I switched it...after remembering to turn it on. Thanks. Hope to write it up with some screen shots soon.